# Exporting model to FBX with specific materials and animations for Spark AR studio

Tags: animation, materials, export, .fbx

I wanted to create a mask for Instagram so I created a model of a character inside a mesh. This character has a face rig that can be animated with textures. It has an upper face with eyes and a bottom face with the mouth, each with a UV. I tried to export it as an .fbx, but these textures don't seem to work then.

Here are nodes for one part of the face (I used mapping to change tiles on one texture image)

[image: nodes for one part of the face (I used mapping to change tiles on one texture image)]

Also I have multiple animations for this model made with Action Editor (they were made into NLA Tracks I think, I've never done multiple animations in one file before) and they also don't seem to work as I intended when exported. I exported with baked animations (key all bones, NLA strips, all actions, force start). The mesh and the character are different armatures.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Maybe there is another file extension I can export with that can preserve these animations? I'm fairly new to Blender.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1):

You can only follow the instructions on the **target platform's site**. Technically, 3/4 of this question is about Spark AR because it is the target platform.

Your automatic reaction to any incompatibility should be to check if the target platform has designed a Blender add on.

As for that add on question:

1)Maybe you know this, but Spark AR has an addon for Blender called the SPARK AR toolkit, download the zip, open preferences, and install it. If it doesn't work on the current Blender version, you may have to try a previous stable one.

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/articles/creating-and-prepping-assets/toolkit-for-blender

[image]

2)read the optimization guidelines and set up your export accordingly, they have a lot of advice:

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/articles/fundamentals/technical-guidelines#optimizing-3d-objects

No worries, you will be able to bring in a **mesh with textures**.

Unfortunately the remaining problems are Spark AR Studio issues.  You may need an **Animation Patch** to loop an animation properly in Spark AR studio.  Reference their site for information on this.

Final notes: The Spark AR toolkit does not export FBX and the type of FBX preferred by Spark AR is *pick*y:

FBX 2014/2015 (binary and ASCII versions)